# how many samples do i need to be sure about my model metrics?

Tags: classification, machine-learning-model

i have 50 features(columns) and 100 samples(rows) dataset for binary classification problem, i have build a ML model by using cross validation and it has model metrics like roc_auc=0.71 f1=0.75 precision=0.62 recall=0.64

My question is , is it enough samples to say that my model have capacity with that metrics to make new predictions? is there any approach like power analysis to say that i need at least n samples to be sure about my ML model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways to screen for this is to use a **learning curve**.

This will graph the training and test accuracy across varying sample sizes. Once a plateau in accuracy growth is observed across increasing sample size, then this is an indication that further samples will be subject to diminishing returns - i.e. have less effect in boosting accuracy.

Please see the following reference: [sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html)

Comment: hi michael , thank you for your answer , so you mean , metrics of test and train sets going to be different if the dataset has not enough sample size ,right?

Comment: Well, yes, one can expect the training and test accuracy to be lower without enough samples - but there will come a point where growth in accuracy slows significantly even when more samples are added. The point of the learning curve is to identify the sample size at which this occurs.